# Pass Report Criteria (picklist value) with links in VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, reporting, outputlink, criteria

I am passing report criteria in a VisualForce page with an outputLink. It works fine where i pass a blank / true / false but when i pass a picklist value, the value does show up in the report filter but the report does not actually filter on that value?

This is my outputLink: (issue is with PV1)

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!'/00Ob0000004MZCF?pv0='&uv['Status__c']&'&pv1=Picklistvalue'&'&pc2=\'\''&'&pc3=\'\''&'&pc4=\'\''&'&pc5=\'\''&'&pc6=\'\''&'&pc7=\'\''&'&pc8=\'\''}"
```

If you are thinking to yourself that this is a rookie mistake - it is because i am a rookie! A rookie that desperately needs a pro's advise please.

Much obliged!

Comment: Could you post the converted HTML of this link using the view source window or inspect element tool?

Comment: Hi Shailesh. The HTML: <a href="https://eu2.salesforce.com/00Ob0000004MZCF?pv0=Unallocated&amp;pv1=Outsurance&amp;pc2=%5C'%5C'&amp;pc3=%5C'%5C'&amp;pc4=%5C'%5C'&amp;pc5=%5C'%5C'&amp;pc6=%5C'%5C'&amp;pc7=%5C'%5C'&amp;pc8=%5C'%5C'" target="_top">OPEN</a>

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. This particular filter is for the object's record type, so i needed to pass the record type id and not the text like with the other filters.